# Can Kbuild build one module for several kernels at once?

Tags: kbuild

Roughly: build against all kernels listed in /lib/modules

E.g:

```
l /lib/modules 
5.3.13-300.fc31.x86_64
5.3.14-300.fc31.x86_64
```

Right now I have an ordinary KBuild and pass the location of the kernel module with -C looks like the following line.

```
[..] -C ${KERNELHEADERS_DIR} modules [...]
```

Is there a way to pass multiple kernel headers into -C of Kbuild?